# Udev rule to create node for character device when loading module

Tags: drivers, udev

I've followed tutorials to make this happen, but I've failed.
My system is Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel `3.18.0-031800-generic`. I've searched for udev rule keys using `udevadm monitor --env`. Its output generated by `rmmod module_name` was

```
KERNEL[202.017039] remove /module/module_name (module)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/module/module_name
SEQNUM=2052
SUBSYSTEM=module

UDEV [202.018837] remove /module/module_name (module)
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/module/module_name
SEQNUM=2052
SUBSYSTEM=module
USEC_INITIALIZED=17116
```

So I've created scripts (and marked them as executable for all) to create and remove node:

```
$ cat /usr/share/another_folder/make_node.sh
#!/bin/sh
mknod /dev/device_name c 89 1

$ cat /usr/share/another_folder/rm_node.sh
#!/bin/sh
rm /dev/device_name
```

And udev rule that uses them:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/89-the-name.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="module", DEVPATH=="/module/module_name", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/share/another_folder/make_node.sh"

SUBSYSTEM=="module", DEVPATH=="/module/module_name", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/usr/share/another_folder/rm_node.sh"
```

...but it doesn't work when I lo (even after restarting udev or rebooting system). `dmesg` doesn't show anything about the case:

```
$ dmesg |grep udev
[    0.928948] systemd-udevd[121]: starting version 204    
[    5.155707] systemd-udevd[316]: starting version 204
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To see what happens you can run

```
sudo udevadm monitor
```

in one terminal and then trigger the wanted event with

```
sudo udevadm trigger --action=add --subsystem-match=module
```

The monitor will show the events seen by udev.

Your problem is probably that in your scripts `mknod` and `rm` are not found as no PATH is set by udev. Use absolute pathnames or set a PATH at the start of the scripts.